# How can I validate current password in the laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, validation, required, change-password, laravel-5.6

I try like this :

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
class ChangePasswordRequest extends FormRequest
{
    ...
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'old_password'              => 'required|confirmed',
            'password'                  => 'required|min:6',
            'password_confirmation'     => 'required|min:6|same:password'
        ];
    }
}
```

I have entered the old password correctly, but there is still a message :

> The old password confirmation does not match.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

what you can do is to make a rule. the following will probably solve your problem.

**CurrentPassword.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Rules;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
class CurrentPassword implements Rule
{
    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        return Hash::check($value,auth()->user()->password);
    }
    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return 'Current password is incorrect';
    }
}
```

and in your controller, you can make something like this:

```
    $this->validate($request,[
        'password_current'=>['required',new CurrentPassword()],
        'password'=>'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);
    $request->user()->update([
        'password'=>bcrypt($request->password)
    ]);
```

Answer (score 2):

(Laravel v7.x)
You are looking for rule called 'password':

```
...

'old_password' => 'password',
...
```

As well you could specify an authentication guard using the rule's first parameter like this:

```
...
'old_password' => 'password|web',
...
```

Here is docs:
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#rule-password

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-confirmed):

*`Hash::check()`* function which allows you to check whether the old password entered by a user is correct or not.

```
if (Hash::check("parameter1", "parameter2")) {
   //add logic here
}

parameter1 - user password that has been entered on the form
parameter2 - old password hash stored in a database
```

It will return true if the old password has been entered correctly and you can add your logic accordingly

*`new_password`* and *`new_confirm_password`* to be same, you can add your validation in form request like this:

```
'new_password'         => 'required',
'new_confirm_password' => 'required|same:new_password'
```

Answer (score 0):

The ["confirmed" rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-confirmed) doesn't do what you expect it here to do.

If you set `confirmed` rule on a field `old_password` it will look for form input `old_password_confirmation` and check that its value is equal to the value of `old_password`. It's basically an inverse of `same:field` with predefined expected name (it will add `_confirmation` to the original name).

In your case you would use it like this and it will perform same function as your current `password_confirmation => same:password` rule:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'old_password'              => 'required',
        'password'                  => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
    ];
}
```

For what you want to achieve you could either [create your own validation rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#custom-validation-rules) or (in my opinion better) check whether the entered password is correct in the controller.